# Linux program like Windows 7 MS Paint

Tags: linux, image-editor, drawing

There are many Linux programs that imitate the MS Paint of Windows XP and earlier. Is there one yet that looks like that of Windows 7 and has the same features?

[image: screenshot of Windows 7 Paint]

Primarily it should look the same as Windows 7 Paint (see the screenshot above), and be easy to use by people who are used to that application. It's all about **“not having trouble switching to Linux”**. In particular:

- The way you can resize the image by dragging the bottom right point at the corner.
- Not to forget its brushes (don't mind if they were a little different), its shapes (must include all shapes), its line thickness resizability and so on.
- The **selection property**; where you select an area in the image and then you may copy it, delete it or whatever (very important).
- It should support a wide range of image formats. I had a problem with that before.

Comment: One more question: do the controls have to be a ribbon thingy? It's a distinctive feature of the user interface, but a much-hated one.

Comment: firstly thank you so much for taking time to edit my question :D ... yeah; preferably should be a ribbon since this is how it looks. I don't hate the ribbon XD XD thanks again :D @gilles

Comment: Of all the features in Windows that could be a barrier to people switching to Linux, I never thought MS Paint would be one of them.

Comment: Then you haven't met me nor my friends :D I used to use paint almost daily! ...makes a big void when switching to Linux but you can't find your simple painting program that you tend to go to whenever you need a simple crop or a simple red circle :D @BenMiller

Comment: To be clear - you want to restrict it to being as simple as MS Paint? So that http://www.gimp.org/ would not be acceptable because it far exceeds MS Paint?

Comment: @Mawg no I just want it to look and behave (have features) like win7 (and further) ms paint

Answer (score 8):

The closest MS Paint clone is [Pinta](https://www.pinta-project.com/).  I regard it as vastly superior to MS Paint, but it retains its simplicity.

All of your needs can be founded easily. Just give it a try.

To install in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install pinta
```

[image: screenshot of Pinta application]

For other Linux distros, or whatever your OS (the app is cross-platform), choose your flavor from here:
https://www.pinta-project.com/releases/

Comment: Thanks but I know Pinta and I have it installed and I love it but the point is it that looks like that of windows xp.

Comment: @MinaMichael you can't find the same Interface, but i think the actions in Pinta is much similar to that in windows7

Comment: And that's why I've included "yet" in my question. thank you so far. :D

Comment: @MinaMichael Then the answer is No One is yet the same :). You are welcome buddy

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there are more alternatives, like [KolourPaint](https://apps.kde.org/kolourpaint/).

I really like it's simplicity.

[image: screenshot of KolourPaint application]

Answer (score 1):

There is https://jspaint.app/ that is an online clone of Windows XP Paint. You probably can save the HTML page with JS and use it offline.